# PowerBI: One can schedule a data refresh, but how can one schedule a report publishing task?

Tags: powerbi

Currently, I have a working dashboard in PowerBI with a data extract that needs to be refreshed several times a day; the visuals are embedded on a website. I need the data refreshes to reflect new data in the embedded visuals.

I know how to schedule a data refresh in PowerBI; assuming that the refresh completes successfully, how can I schedule the publishing of the dashboards?

I ask because although my data refreshes are working, the embedded visuals don't update until I manually publish each one through PowerBI.

Does anyone know how I can automate the second half of this process?

Comment: Are you using [Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/) or embedding through [Publish to web](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/)? Either way, the embedded visuals should be updated when data refresh is done. Can you share more about the details or an example?

Comment: @FoxanNg, finally, the files began updating according to schedule and the updates began appearing online. I don't know what engendered the error before, but thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 types of refresh:

1. Package refresh
2. **Model/data refresh** (what you referred to as the first half of the process)
3. **Tile refresh** (2nd half of the process)
4. Visual container refresh

**1** is not relevant for your scenario.
**2** is handled by scheduling a refresh, it refreshes the dataset in the Power BI service as you mentioned.
**3** is the update of the cache for tile visuals on the dashboard, once data changes. This happens (automatically) about every 15 minutes.
You can also force a tile refresh by selecting the ellipse (...) in the upper right of a dashboard and selecting Refresh dashboard tiles.

[image: You]

**4** is used for refreshing the cached report visuals in a report, once the data changes.

You can take a look [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-refresh-data/) for more info.

Comment: @daonlybg if that answered your question, could you mark it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, that didn't answer my question- refreshing the tiles does indeed refresh the dashboard that's kept on app.powerbi.com, but not visuals embedded on my personal website.

Comment: I don't know why this happened, but the reports began updating according to schedule and the updates are visible in the online embedded report. I'm going to select your answer because it's detailed and provides a good resource.

Comment: That's pretty strange.. Thanks